# Working with List of numbers in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have a loop of buttons, ranging from 1-100 (this varies, could be 1-50), if a user selects any of the button it populates an input field e.g 32, 47, 84, 69.

So i have a django view that saves it to the database but it is saved in the database in this format [u'32', u'47', u'84', u'69'] which i know will be regarded as one entity, but i need the numbers to be regarded as separate entity, so that any number that is in the database, wont be selected by any other user.

```
def game_details(request, id):
    template_name = 'app_agent_games/game_details.html'
    get_game_id = get_object_or_404(gamesModel, id=id)
    context = {
        'game_details': get_game_id,
        'range': range(1, get_game_id.people + 1)
    }
    if request.POST:
        guesses = request.POST.get('guessed_number', False)
        splited = guesses.split(',')
        counter = request.POST.get('count_guess', False)
        update_game = PlayGameForm(request.POST)
        obj = PlayGame()
        obj.guessed_number = splited
        obj.total_stake = int(get_game_id.amount) * int(counter)
        obj.game_id = get_object_or_404(gamesModel, id=id)
        obj.agent_id = get_object_or_404(CustomAgent, user_id=request.user.user_id)
        obj.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/games/details/'+id)
    return render(request, template_name, context)
```

The model structure:

```
class PlayGame(models.Model):
    agent_id = models.ForeignKey(CustomAgent, related_name='agent_game')
    game_id = models.ForeignKey(gamesModel, related_name='agent_game_id')
    guessed_number = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    total_stake = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

The model field that saves the list is guessed_number

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need a slightly more evolved data model:

```
class PlayGame(models.Model):
    agent_id = models.ForeignKey(CustomAgent, related_name='agent_game')
    game_id = models.ForeignKey(gamesModel, related_name='agent_game_id')
    total_stake = models.IntegerField(default=0)

class GameNumber(models.Model):
    game = models.ForeignKey(PlayGame)
    number = models.IntegerField()
    user = models.ForeignKey('YourUser', blank=True, null=True)
```

Then, for example, you create all your numbers `1-100` for your game, and if a user guessed it, set the user FK to be the user who guessed it, else keep the user FK null.

Comment: Numbers 1-100 may change, another game may have 1-200, 1-50. it varies